# "s" suffix usage for words "electronic" and "communication"

Tags: word-usage

Specifically I want to know in this context:

> - Electronics and Communications Engineering
> - Electronic and Communication Engineering
> - Electronics and Communication Engineering
> - Electronic and Communications Engineering

Which is correct?

Comment: any thoughts yourself?

Comment: Our department is called Electronic and Telecommunication Engineering Department. But for some reason (I don't know why) I use "Electronics and Telecommunications Engineering Department" _mistakenly_. When I googled I found all four!

Comment: Since all four are used by various establishments, why should any be considered incorrect? The adjective vs attributive noun issue has been covered on ELU before, though this particular question does also involve the plural- vs singular-form attributive noun choice (also covered before).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at UK university courses, *Electronic* seems to be preferred to *Electronics*  but both *Communication* and *Communications* are used.

Examples:

- Kent: [Electronic and Communications Engineering](https://www.kent.ac.uk/courses/undergraduate/212/electronic-and-communications-engineering-beng)
- York: [Electronic and Communication Engineering](https://www.york.ac.uk/electronic-engineering/undergraduate/courses/comms/)
- KC London: [Electronic Engineering](https://www.kcl.ac.uk/study/undergraduate/courses/electronic-engineering-beng.aspx)
- Manchester: [Communication Engineering](http://www.manchester.ac.uk/study/masters/courses/list/04211/msc-communication-engineering/)
- Aston: [Communications Engineering](http://www.aston.ac.uk/study/undergraduate/courses/eas/beng-communications-engineering/)

Comment: And then there is the question of why *Electrical Engineering* and *Mechanical Engineering* but not *Electronical Engineering*